# Read-only users?

Tags: trello, trello-organization, trello-cards

Is it possible to set the privileged of users as read-only?  I have looked through the settings to no avail.

Another possibility is to create a second board for all the would-be read only users.

Comment: You can make a board visible to (but not editable by) members of the organization that a board is in.

Answer (score 1):

By default, when you add a user to an organization they get read-only access to the boards, only when they're added as a member of a board do they gain write-access.