# Does Trello support read-only access?

Tags: trello

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Read-only users?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/37756/read-only-users)

Does Trello support editability restrictions such that I can constrain certain users to read-only access?

If yes where can I learn how to set that up?